# scala & lift: rewriting URL using variable declared outside LiftRules.statelessRewrite.append

Tags: scala, url-rewriting, lift

I'm looking for a solution for rewriting URLs in lift using a list declared outside the scope of `LiftRules.statelessRewrite.append`

```
LiftRules.statelessRewrite.append {  
    case RewriteRequest(ParsePath("abc" :: Nil, _ , _ , _ ), _ , _ ) =>  
        RewriteResponse("index" :: Nil)
}
```

I'd like to have the following code working the same as the one above:

```
val requestList = "abc" :: Nil

LiftRules.statelessRewrite.append {  
    case RewriteRequest(ParsePath(requestList, _ , _ , _ ), _ , _ ) =>
        RewriteResponse("index" :: Nil)
}
```

Could anyone write how to get such functionality with lift 2.0?

[**edit**]

Could you also suggest the best way to access this list's suffix as parameter. What I would like to get is similar to:

```
LiftRules.statelessRewrite.append {  
  case RewriteRequest(ParsePath(`requestList` ::: List(someId), _ , _ , _ ), _ , _ ) =>  
    RewriteResponse("index" :: Nil, Map("someId" -> someId))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any lowercased variable in a `case` statement will create a new variable with that name, therefore `requestList` is going to be shadowed. Try this:

```
val requestList = "abc" :: Nil

LiftRules.statelessRewrite.append {
  case RewriteRequest(ParsePath(list, _ , _ , _ ), _ , _ ) if list == requestList =>
    RewriteResponse("index" :: Nil)
}
```

Another approach would be to use backticks (Scala ref: ‘stable identifier patterns’):

```
LiftRules.statelessRewrite.append {
  case RewriteRequest(ParsePath(`requestList`, _ , _ , _ ), _ , _ ) =>
    RewriteResponse("index" :: Nil)
}
```

In your case, the second form would be the canonical one to choose, but in general the first form will be more powerful.

As a third alternative, you could also define `val RequestList = requestList` and match against the uppercased version, though I would advise against this unless you have a good reason for creating a capitalised `RequestList`.